# Processing- how to write; "On mouse click in region". For effect of clicking a button

Tags: if-statement, button, processing

I was wondering why this code doesn't work as intended.

```
void mousePressed() {

    if (mouseX > width-50 && mouseX < width && mouseY > height-50 && mouseY < height)
    { 
        img = loadImage("doraemon.png");
        image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
    }
```

I want it so that when I click on an image that says 'next', I can show a different image on the background, and if clicked again, show another background image and so on.

```
if (mouseX > width-50 && mouseX < width && mouseY > height-50 && mouseY < height)
```

^This code snippet states where the button 'next' is. 
When I run this code, I get an image while hovering over the condition, but I want the image to appear after I press the button.

Does anyone know how to write that?

I need something like

```
 if (mousePressed == condition)
     { 
      then change image
     }
```

Please help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to cram all of your logic into the `mousePressed()` function. Instead, you need to split your logic up between the `mousePressed()` function and the `draw()` function. Use variables to keep track of what should be drawn. Adjust those variables in the `mousePressed()` function. Use those variables to figure out what to draw in the `draw()` function.

A simple example might look like this:

```
boolean showButton1 = true;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
}

void mousePressed() {
  if (mouseX < 100 && mouseY < 100) {
    //button 1 was just clicked, show button 2 instead
    showButton1 = false;
  } else if (mouseX > 100 && mouseY > 100) {
    //button 2 was just clicked, show button 1 instead
    showButton1 = true;
  }
}

void draw() {

  background(0);

  if (showButton1) { //draw the first button
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  } else { //draw the second button
    fill(0, 255, 0);
    rect(100, 100, 100, 100);
  }
}
```

Also, you shouldn't call `loadImage()` from the `mousePressed()` or `draw()` functions. Instead, load your images from the `setup()` function, and store them in variables that you can use later.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of things look a slightly off in the snippet you posted:

```
if (mouseX > width-50 && mouseX < width && mouseY > height-50 && mouseY < height)
    { 
        img = loadImage("doraemon.png");
        image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
    }
```

One is minor: you're loading the image each time there is mouse click a 50x50 box at the bottom right edge of your sketch. You should load the image once in setup, then simply re-use it when you need it through your sketch.

The second might be your main issue: you call `image()` only once if the mouse is pressed (and in the bottom right side of your sketch). This means that if you have a `background()` call or other drawing calls in the `draw()` function, you will barely notice the Doraemon image being drawn (as it is erased/painted over more often)

Here's what I mean in code:

```
PImage img;//reference to the image
boolean imgDraw;//keep track if the image should be drawn or not

void setup(){
  //load the image only once, at setup
  img = loadImage("doraemon.png");
  size(img.width,img.height);
}
void draw(){
  background(0);//clear each frame
  if(imgDraw){//draw the image only if it needs to be drawn
    image(img, 0, 0, width, height);
  }
}
void mousePressed() {
    //check if the cursor is at the bottom right, and if so, set the image draw flag to true
    if (mouseX > width-50 && mouseX < width && mouseY > height-50 && mouseY < height)
    { 

        imgDraw = true;
    }
    else
    {
      imgDraw = false;
    }  
}
```

Actually, because, the imgDraw is a boolean and you have a boolean expression checking coordinates, you can collapse it to a single statement.

```
void mousePressed(){
  imgDraw = (mouseX > width-50 && mouseX < width && mouseY > height-50 && mouseY < height); 
}
```

Looks, nice but if the code is harder to read, it's not worth it.
Readable code is better.

Comment: Thank you very much! This has solved me a lot of questions. Your very detailed explanation really helps!